# HEX to ASCII to HEX Conversion : Unreadable Characters

Tags: gps, hex, ascii

Whenever i tried to convert HEX (12 11 80 64 29 86) to ASCII, it print out unreadable characters.

12 11 80 64 29 86 - > d)

What is this d) and how can i make it readable?

I'm working with a GPS unit and it send me data through TCP.

Here is a full message

$$ ▒▒d)▒▒▒U071121.000,A,2047.6419,N,09702.6721,E,0.11,185,080718,,*0C|1.0|1409|0000|0001,0000,0000,028A|019E00010C819D45|1E|0006F055|08i-

I need unreadable characters before U071121 in HEX as it represent the device ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ascii table with printable and non printable characters: https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-v-uppercase-ascii-code-86.html

Here is the hex version: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html

I suspect that your 3rd and 6th characters are outside the ascii character set.

Note that hex is base 16. 12 in hex is 18 in decimal.

Comment: how can i convert it to HEX?

Comment: Here is a hex (base 16) to ascii table: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html

Comment: 80 and 86 in hex are too big to map to simple ascii codes.

Comment: Im getting "2592 2592 64 29 2592 2592 2592"  when i convert "▒▒d)▒▒▒"

Comment: I should be getting 12 11 80 64 29 86

Comment: Here is the hex version: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html

Comment: Hex is base 16 so 12 => (1× 16) + 2 = 18

Comment: Your third and sixth numbers are too large for standard ascii.

Comment: Are you sure that these are not decimal. (form feed) (vertical tab) P @ (group seperator) V   These are mostly non printable characters so don't print them!

Comment: The supplier said the data from GPS unit is transmitted in HEX data. Somehow, my server is converting it into ASCII automatically.
So, im lost. Could be in decimal.

Comment: Do you have a spec of what they are sending?

Comment: Log file
http://www.mediafire.com/file/qbq2rfai925b5v2/08-Jul-18%266-22-25%20PM.txt

Comment: Protocol
http://www.mediafire.com/file/c5mn4cv843eee8p/Example%20of%20VT600%20GPRS%20Protocol%20Integration.docx

Comment: Try asking a more specific question. You need to say what language/library you are using and what you have tried. SO users won't download large specs and sample kits.